Effect on Thrust and Power Required Curves of Flaps
I know for a fact that the extension of flaps shifts the thrust required/total drag curve higher. How do I prove mathematically that it also shifts to the left (LDmax with flaps extended occurs at a lower airspeed)? I've played around with the math of the induced and parasite drag curves trying to find an expression for where they intersect, and how flaps would change this expression. I've also looked at finding the bottom of the total drag curve (where the rate of change becomes zero),and looking at how that changes with flaps.
Thank you

You may need a POH-data calibrated power curve to see how thrust changes with flaps.

There are a few ways to go about this.
Starting from a simple parabolic drag polar $C_D=C_{D,0}+K\, {C_L}^2$, you can find that best $L/D$ occurs at ${C_L}^*=\sqrt{C_{D,0} / K}$
If you assume that deploying flaps only increases the parasite drag (increases  $C_{D,0}$), then it is clear to see that deploying flaps will increase the lift coefficient for best $L/D$.  Increased ${C_L}^*$ means you must fly slower to achieve that speed (all else being equal -- Weight, reference wing area, density).
However, if you have partial span flaps, you can reasonably assume that they will not only degrade the parasite drag (increases  $C_{D,0}$), but they will also degrade the quality of the lift distribution and thereby increase induced drag (increase $K$).  In this case, whether the speed for best $L/D$ shifts left or right depends on which has a greater change -- parasite drag, or induced drag.

Yes, this is good. Only thing I'd add/modify is V for L/Dmax is proportional to the fourth root of (K/Cdo). So, depends on whether K or Cdo has a greater percentage change.

Flaps both increase CD0, and shift the CL at which CD0 occurs.
If you have access to ESDU, paper 08013 goes through this for 2d, which is also reasonable for rough work in 3d. They also provide all kinds of equations to analytically estimate the actual change in 3d, but it's not as straightforward.
In general, CD,0 shifts in CL by half the amount the liftcurve shifts by, but the change in CD,0 itself is less straightforward.

A 2D approach to this will not capture how the induced drag is affected.  It is equivalent to saying that only CD0 changes -- not K (or a parabolic polar).
